# How to access file in documents folder?

Tags: java, android, file, exception, permissions

Im trying to acces a file from the documents folder, but it's always throws an exception.. What is the correct code for that path? Im using a samsung SM-G950F Android 8.0.0

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdcard/Documents/asd.txt");
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Documents/asd.txt (No such file or directory)

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/Documents/asd.txt");
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Documents/asd.txt (Permission denied)

Im getting a permission denied here and i have these permissions in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File` object would be created via:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "asd.txt");
```

And, [as Igor points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53251228/115145), you will need to request runtime permissions for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: I have 1 more problem, it in the email I just get the file, without any extension (example: sending erve.pdf only getting erve as a file, no extension). I have to change someting at  'File' object creating?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it, I used  .setFileName(); and that messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 6.0 you have to ask for permissions https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem! Thanks! :D